# How to retrieve a variable from the object msg?

Tags: node-red

I'm new to node-red and I've been trying to create a new variable following the example of the doc http://nodered.org/docs/writing-functions.html
Here's the code :

```
// initialise the counter to 0 if it doesn't exist already
var count = context.get('count')||0;
count += 1;
// store the value back
context.set('count',count);
// make it part of the outgoing msg object
msg.count = count;
return msg;
```

But then I have trouble using the variable msg.count. I've made a message trying to print the value with multiple attempts such as `{msg.count}` or `{msg.get('count')}` but it writes `undefined` or nothing each time.
How can I print the variable count?
This is what the flow looks like, the switch simply checking the value of msg.count.

[image]

Comment: You need to explain where you are trying to access `msg.count`. A description of your flow (or a screenshot) would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying too complicated.
I simply had to use `{count}` instead of `{msg.count}`.